Fastboot does not flash patched boot (infinite sending boot)
I tried to do fastboot flash boot patched_boot.img
but it gives me back

Warning: skip copying boot image avb footer (boot partition size: 0, boot image size: 61865984).
Sending 'boot' (60416 KB)

when I unplug the cable it says

FAILED (Status read failed (Too many links))
fastboot: error: Command failed

Also I tried to do fastboot boot patched_boot.img but it infinitely Sending 'boot.img' (60416 KB)
I unplugged the cable - same thing.
I have Samsung galaxy m31.
What to do?

I assume you are trying to install Magisk? Please read the documentation about Samsung flash tools first: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-devices Samsung devices are not flashed with fastboot.

@Robert, alright, but how do i flash boot (boot.img) in odin (ik what odin is, i just dont know how to flash boot in odin)

https://xdaforums.com/t/rooting-a-samsung-device-using-magisk-and-odin-2023.4594475/

@Robert, yea ik the AP patch method but the phone reboots into downloading mode and then says "VBA Fail: hash mismatch" or smth

Samsung devices don't have fastboot mode. You're trying to flash boot partition in fastbootd mode. Flashing bootloader, radio, and boot/recovery from fastbootd is unsupported.
